# how to prevent PLAY and PAUSE click operation on jwplayer5 video, ONLY when set to FULLSCREEN MODE?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer 5 and I need a way to prevent to execute click operation (Play if paused and Pause if in play) when my video is set on full screen mode.

I am not able to manage it. Is there a solution?

here's the video:

```
var video1 = jwplayer('vid1').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'html/js/jwplayer5/player.swf',
            'id': 'playerVid1',
            'width': VIDPLAYER_CTRL.BIGVIDEO_WIDTH,
            'height': VIDPLAYER_CTRL.BIGVIDEO_HEIGHT,
            'file': VIDPLAYER_MODEL.MAIN_VIDEO['path'],
            'provider': 'http',
            'startparam': 'start',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'image': VIDPLAYER_MODEL.MAIN_VIDEO['path_img'],
            'skin': 'html/js/jwplayer5/videoSkin/videoSkin.xml'
            //'plugins': 'clickproxy',
            //'clickproxy.state' : 'play'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JW5:

Use this plugin - http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/68/Clickproxy

Set the "plugins" variable to "clickproxy"

Set the variable "clickproxy.state" to "play"

Your player will no longer be clickable.

I am not sure how to make this specific to fullscreen mode, though.

Comment: ehy @Ethan LongTail, now my customised controlbar skin is not clickable anymore...  so I've another problem, because I can't put on fullscreen mode anymore. is this a limit of JwPlayer, or am I missing something? because my goal is to use my customised skin only, and avoid the user to put pause and play clicking on the video surface. now I'm asking if it's possible....

Comment: hmmm, good question. Do you have a link I can look at? I would have to see it to be 100% sure, but might not be possible.

Comment: I can not put a link, because it's a work in progress of a private project. it's ok, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, but we require links for proper debugging.